# Word count in C?

Tags: c, count, std, words

I have a problem with counting words in `std`. I use the same method when I count words in files there works OK.
My method is as follows: We read until `ctrl+d`. If the next character is a line return, increase `new_lines`. Otherwise, we increase the words because the next method (last if) doesn't read until first space and I lost first word. In the end If the current character is a space and next element is something other than a space, increase words.

Now I'm going to explain about problem. If I have empty line program increase words but why I use second if for this. If I don't have empty lines program work.

```
int status_read=1;

while (status_read > 0){ // read to end of file

   status_read = read(STDOUT_FILENO, buff, 9999);   // read from std    
        for (i = 0; i < status_read ; i++) { // until i<status_read 
            if (buff[i] == '\n') { 
                new_lines++;
                if (buff[i+1]!='\n')  
                    wordcounter++;  
             }  
            if (buff[i] == ' ' && buff[i+1]!=' ') 
                    wordcounter++;  
        }   
    }
```

Comment: So this program works, somewhere, properly handling blank lines?  But somewhere else, it does not?  What are the differences between these two situations?

Comment: Did you mean to read `STDIN_FILENO`, perhaps?

Comment: `buff[i + 1]` may look beyond the array boundary. It is probably better to keep track of the previously read character and to initialise that to space, so that there is an imaginary space before your input.

Comment: Your current program marks a word when you cross the border from space to non-space. But "space" is not a single characters; it is a concept that comprises various characters: space, tab, newline. You can look into `<ctype.h>` for the function `isspace`, which may be useful to you.

Comment: @ScottHunter yes when Program reads Files work OK but when read from std has problem.I use the same code.

Answer (score 0):

As @FredLarson commented, you are trying to read from standard *out*, not standard *in* (that is, you should be using `STDIN_FILENO`, not `STDOUT_FILENO`).

Comment: Ok I changed it but I have the same result like STDOUT.

Comment: Then maybe you should explain what that result is, since you've never actually explained what that is.

Comment: The result is wrong when I have empty lines.E.G->If I input  4 enters program counts 4 words.

Answer (score 0):

> If I have empty line program increase words but why I use second if
>   for this. If I don't have empty lines program work.

That's due to

```
            if (buff[i] == '\n') { 
                new_lines++;
                if (buff[i+1]!='\n')  
                    wordcounter++;  
             }
```

- to solve this problem, just don't increment `wordcounter` here - replace the above with

```
            if (buff[i] == '\n') ++new_lines;
```

> Otherwise,
>   we increase the words because the next method (last if) doesn't read
>   until first space and I lost first word.

To avoid the problem of losing the first word on a line, as well as that with `buff[i+1]` (see M Oehm's comments above), I suggest changing

```
            if (buff[i] == ' ' && buff[i+1]!=' ') 
                    wordcounter++;
```

to

```
            if (wasspace && !isspace(buff[i])) ++wordcounter;  
            wasspace = isspace(buff[i]);
```

- `wasspace` being defined and initialized to `int wasspace = 1;` before the file read loop.